# Telerik MVC Extension conflicts with JqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, telerik

I am trying to use Telerik MVC extension with jQGrid in a ASP.NET MVC application. But I found they cannot nicely play each other, meaning I cannot have them working together in one View. No sure why? I guess it is because the place for js files. JqGrid needs to put the js library in Head, but Telerik requires before end of Body tag, based on its instruction. I tried to move this piece of code see below above. Telerik MVC extension does not work any more. Does anybody get them work smoothly? Actually, I can use JQuery UI, which Telerik's built up on. But Telerik's fluent API looks better.

```
   <%
        Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                      .Render();
    %>
```

**Update:**

Now, I should be able to get them work together.

First, in Site.Master, add another content after Telerik script render like:

```
<%
     Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
              .Render();
%>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
```

Then, in the View, add the script specific for view in ScriptContent. Then everything works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now disable the automatic jQuery including:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

http://jmvcui.codeplex.com/

They are also MVC helper methods for jQuery UI.   Perhaps there won't be a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the inclusion of jQuery from Telerik ScriptRegistar script manager is in question.
korchev's solution worked for me, but i'm curious if Telerik components would work fine since there are different versions of jQuery